# What can cause the front wheel to lock up when going over a small bump?

Tags: wheels, safety, electric-bike, front

I was going over a bump. When the front wheel hit the bump, it suddenly stopped moving, the rear wheel lifted off the ground, and I was thrown face-first onto the road. I sustained injuries to the face, hands, chest and knees, and had to go to emergency (see edit 2 for photograph of injuries).

I'm fine now, but I wanted to understand this so that I can be safe next time.

This happened with two different cycles, so I know it's not a defect specific to a unit or to a model. One was an e-bike, with small wheels (maybe a foot in diameter), poor or no suspension, and was going at its maximum speed of 25kph.

Since I was asked, here's a photo of my riding posture:

[image]

The brake:

[image]

And the brake lever:

[image]
(These were taken on another unit of the same model, but they're identical AFAIK.)

The other cycle has the usual-sized wheels, no suspension, and was going at 25kph or slightly slower.

In both cases:

- I was going more or less straight.
- The road was dry.
- I never pressed either brake.
- The bump was tiny, half a cm at most, and the bike can navigate much bigger bumps at full speed safely.
- The road was otherwise smooth.
- It was the front wheel that caught the bump.
- I was thrown over the handlebars.
- There was no indication of anything going wrong before I was thrown over the handlebars — no skidding, no scraping sound, no loss of balance, nothing.
- The vehicle didn't have apparent damage either before or after the incident.
- I wasn't carrying any loads.
- I didn't have loose clothing that can get stuck somewhere.
- I wasn't applying the brakes.

Is it because the bump caused the front brake to apply spontaneously? Is there anything I can do to be safe, because at this point, I'm a little concerned about using bicycles or e-bikes any more.

Comment: You really mean 0.5cm? Is it possible you always ride with hands ready on the brake levers, and accidentally squeezed them as a reaction to hitting the bump, possibly without noticing? You are yourself the common factor in the 2 cases apart from the bump, and the chances a tiny bump would somehow lockup anything on the bike itself are small (i.e. so hard to find a mechanical reason which makes any kind of real-life sense). What brakes were on the 2 bikes? Or do you perhaps know the exact models?

Comment: Were these incidents on significant downhills? Or immediately preceded by a dip in the road surface? Either would shift weight onto the front wheel before you even hit the bump; the latter also compresses the tyre and any suspension, reducing its ability to handle the bump. A flat tyre also reduces your ability to roll over bad surfaces. Any difference in loading (heavy front bag for example)?

Comment: Would also be nice to know if there was anything visibly wrong with the bikes after this happened. E.g. is the wheel still firm in place? Theoretically if the axle breaks in a bad way and somehow gets caught in the hub I assume it could cause the lock-up. But, just like Carbon's answer: this should be dicoverable after the fact. Whereas when the bikes are still fine there's more pointers towards brakes having engaged.

Comment: @ChrisH It was a flat road, not downhill, not really a dip, and no heavy bags or other difference in loading (just me on the bike). I wasn't leaning forward to load the front wheel, for example. In the recent case involving the e-bike, it was a depression in the road, like a channel eroded by water, if that helps you visualise. It was probably half a cm deep, a few cm wide, and maybe 10 cm long. The walls weren't steep enough that the tyre could get caught in it. If that were the case, I would have steered away from it in the first place.

Comment: @stijn Yes, it was only 0.5cm, which is why I found this surprising. The e-bike is a Yulu Miracle: https://www.google.com/search?q=yulu+miracle&oq=yulu+miracle&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1687j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Sorry, I don't have a better link. I don't think my hands were on the brake levers, because it was a wide road with less traffic, so I actually relaxed at that point. I had no sensation of hitting the bump, for me to even accidentally squeeze the brake levers. The sensation was that one moment I was traveling normally, and in the next I was flying through the air.

Comment: @stijn The e-bike has mechanical drum brakes on the front. (And electrically activated brakes on the rear, though that's probably irrelevant.) Any more info I can give you help you help me?

Comment: Side comment - a helmet worn properly (ie down over the forehead) would have saved you most if not all of the damage to the face.  Do consider wearing a helmet.

Comment: Is it a rental electric scooter - something you don't own?  If you do own the bike, please  provide some clear photos so we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: Did both events happen in the same place?  Please consider stopping there and adding a photo of the cause to your question too.   Or provide a link on Google Maps Street view if its useful.

Comment: Photos of the bike, ideally with you in riding position might be helpful.

Comment: @Criggie Good point, and I'll wear one next time, but I took the impact on my face, not head, and knees, chest and hands, so it would have helped partially at best. Still, good of you to remind everyone of this. The events happened in different cities separated by 20 years. I will send a photo as soon as I'm well enough to go out. Yes, it's a rental e-bike, but I can send a photo of myself on another unit of the same model. Street View is unavailable in India, so I can't share that, and it's unlikely to have the resolution for this purpose.

Comment: @Criggie I checked with the CEO of the company, and he says he doesn't think there's any damage to the bike I rode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asker says in comments the vehicle involved was a [Yulu Miracle](https://www.google.com/search?q=yulu+miracle&oq=yulu+miracle&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1687j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) pedal-less electric scooter

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus You've misrepresented the situation. I mentioned in the question that the same incident happened on a bicycle.

Comment: @mattnz I've updated the question with the photos.

Comment: @stijn I updated the question with photos.

Comment: Got to love the comedy suspension fork on that scooter.  With a wheel that small and a head angle that steep it's going to do virtually nothing.  And by the look of it, even if it did something the mudguard would collide with the frame before using half the available travel

Comment: @VaddadiKartick in the question and comments you primarily refer to the incident in the escooter. You only mention you happened to have crashed a bicycle in similar circumstances 20 years ago

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus But the circumstances were exactly the same — front wheel locked up, road level, not wet, no usual loading, half-cm bump, no loose clothing, no apparent damage to vehicle before the incident or after... So the issues discussed in the question and answer apply to both cycles, don't they? BTW does "bicycles" exclude e-bikes? The Yulu Miracle in question is halfway between a bicycle and a scooter. Unlike https://medium.com/redact/bounce-dockless-scooter-sharing-raises-3-million-from-innoven-capital-991b6bf815e4 — if it was about this, I agree this is not the right forum.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick it has no pedals - its not a bicycle.  It has more in common with a low powered motorbike.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick I can't see how you can say the circumstances were the same as they were in different cities and decades apart.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus How does the city and year change the laws of physics? My previous comment describes the factors that were the same between the bicycle and the e-bike.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus If you want I can edit the question and my comments and answers to remove all mention and photos of the e-bike, though that will confuse people given the existing answers and comments.

Comment: I kind of wonder if the front fender was briefly deformed by the bump, causing it to catch the tire.  Then it sprang back and said "Who, me?"

Comment: @DanielRHicks Interesting theory, but unlikely, since the bump was tiny, and the vehicle navigated bigger bumps with ease at speed.

Comment: @danielrhicks at that speed, the plastic cap would have come off or disintegrated, and in order for the front wheel to come to a sudden stop, the metal edge would be bent/torn. OP, was there a loud scratching or metallic noise before impact?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick a properly-worn helmet has a "ledge" over the eyes - not the visor, but an area to protect the face from "mudsucking" slides.

Comment: @dlatikay No sound, whether metallic or otherwise. It was as if an invisible hand reached out and suddenly held the front wheel in place.

Comment: This question really does not belong here.  You're asking for an open-ended list of ideas, which is outside the mission of stack exchange sites.  Then the documentation of your actual incident shows it to be the result of an unsafe electric scooter design, not any sort of bicycle, making pretty much all of the bike responses irrelevant.  Unless you can provide details of an actual pedal **bicycle** incident, including things like if the wheel turns freely *now*, this question really needs to be closed and deleted, or migrated to a place for motor scooter topics.

Comment: The thing on the picture has nothing to do with a bike, except it has wheels. And it looks like a children toy, not something that can be driven on the street. It looks terribly unsafe.

Comment: Agree with Chris Stratton and Argenti Apparatus that this feels off topic. The question is primarily about an electric scooter that has no option for pedal-driven propulsion, and secondarily refers in much less detail to a related crash on a traditional bicycle many years ago. If you still want an answer to your question, it would help to add more detail about the crash on the real bicycle, although presumably that's difficult so many years later.

Comment: ... having said that, if others are game to continue entertaining this question, I think it would help to provide a picture of where the crash actually occured. This should be easy since you mention you ride that route every day. When it is safe to do so (watch for cars), stop where you crashed, and take a couple of pictures of where it happened and the bump you think caused the crash. Add them to your question.

Comment: @SSilk I went to the scene of the accident, as you asked, but couldn't identify the exact spot, because the bump that caused the accident was so small

Comment: @VaddadiKartick good work thank you.  I think you're over-focussing on this bump.  If its so small that you can't identify the exact spot, then there's no way this bump could have thrown you off the bike.   I suspect your rental bike was faulty, or the brake activated, or something got stuck in your wheel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appeared at the top of my feed after two years and its STILL not about bicycles

Comment: I'd call it an e-bike, but not of the pedelec variety we're familiar with in many countries.  It might not be a bike under (e.g.) UK law, lacking pedals, but it's built from bike components (many of them customised, but definitely bike components).  It's not made with motor-scooter components (even electric ones) and the seated position makes it not an (electric) kick-scooter.  It's an odd bike, and I wouldn't fancy riding it, but it's closer to a bike than to anything else

Answer (score 9):

If you have quick-release or bolt-up front axle that is not properly tightened, then going over a bump could cause it to come out of the fork dropouts. Normally dropouts are equipped with [lawyer tabs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end) to prevent this, but they aren't 100% effective or your bike may not even have them. Once it drops out of the dropout, the fork would then no longer be supported and would drop onto the tyre brining it to an abrupt stop, likely catapulting the rider over the bars.

Comment: You'd think the wheel being detached from the bike would be fairly obvious, but if it dropped enough for the brake pads to hit the tyre, that could stop the wheel turning without it escaping. With brakes adjusted very close to the tyre this could happen even with lawyer lips.

Comment: I do remember my rear wheel getting stuck when I don't put it in the dropouts properly, but I'm not sure this is what's happening.

Comment: From experience (long story, QR was loose, probaly by someone who did not like where i parked my bike) You don't wonder if the front wheel fell off.  You go over the bump, and is dawns on you there was no 'landing' and the front of the bike is 'sinking', you look down have enough time to think "that's a strange place for the front wheel, oh ...., this is going to hurt".

Comment: @mattnz Ah, that didn't happen to me.

Comment: I updated the question with photos.

Answer (score 7):

**This is inexplicable** and we're missing some details.

Any modern bike tyre will be 20mm wide as a bare minimum.  Your electric scooter appears to have approximately 2" or 50mm tyres from the photos.

As such a 5 mm bump will be no more than a quarter of the tyre - its not even going to snake-bite at normal pressures.  At 10% the height of the scooter's tyre it shouldn't even be noticeable.

Here's my guesses and why

- The rental bike was poorly maintained and there's something significantly wrong with it.
- Complete and unexpected failure of a bearing would jerk the bike suddenly.
- The electric brake "suffered an uncommanded activation" - that is it came on without your input (less likely - would have been a big skid not an OTB)
- Some other rider shoved an obstruction into your wheel unnoticed, or a stick lodged into your wheel unnoticed.  This would have broken/dented/bent spokes and probably put a mark on the fork.
- Something you're carrying caught a spoke unnoticed.
- Something you're carrying wedged in between a wheel and the frame, or a wheel and the brake.
- Something was across the road that you didn't see - a trip wire.
- The hole was much deeper than you realised?  Perhaps measure it.

All in all I feel there's some assumed knowledge that we're missing, hence the request for photos.   I'm not doubting you, just there's something unstated.

Given there's two different bikes, with similar reactions, I am wondering if the common factor is the rider, your technique, your clothing, your shoes, or even something you're not aware of, like your physical ratios, or your bone structure affecting posture leading to something.

This is a fascinating question - please add more info and we'll see where it goes.

Comment: Thanks very much. To answer your questions: I wasn't carrying anything. I didn't feel a jerk at all. It was traveling smoothly and the next thing I know I was flying in the air. No wire across the road. I travel by the same road every day to office. If the electric brake spontaneously activated, that's the rear brake — the front one isn't electric and that's the wheel that suddenly stopped. I had no loose clothing. As far as my posture, I often slouch, but nothing else I'm aware of.

Comment: I updated the question with photos

Comment: @VaddadiKartick  All I can think of is maybe the scooter was faulty.  And I'm gobsmacked that you weren't wearing a helmet on a motorbike even a small one like that.

Comment: Thanks for the critical comment — I'll wear one from now on.

Answer (score 3):

**Something getting stuck between the spokes**

It's feasible that some foreign object gets in  between the spokes and locks the wheel on contact with the fork. It can be a stick laying on the road, but given that OP hasn't noticed it it could be something hanging on the bike, maybe there's some accessory you used on both bikes when the accidents happened?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTLSgne_TWQ  An accessory would explain it happening twice to the same person.

Comment: I wasn't using any accessory, and there was nothing on the road. It fact, it was wide open, trash-free and generally a pleasant stretch.

Comment: I updated the question with photos.

Comment: @Vaddadi Kartick can you inspect the whole again, I'm thinking there might be another hidden whole, maybe covered in soil or water in the middle of it that's actually much deeper. Try to poke something in the middle of it. * I assume both accidents happened on the same place

Comment: I will do so when I'm well enough to go out, but the wheel should've traveled over a tiny hole that's much deeper. Both accidents happened in different places, but the question describes all the ways in which they were similar.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's not much detail provided about the physical surroundings of the crash (i.e. no pictures of the road surface or the bump you hit), we're all really stabbing in the dark here. I'll continue that trend...

Looking at the front brake of the bike, it appears to be cable actuated and the cable pulls back on that brass arm. Suppose there was a small hard object in the road that you didn't notice, e.g. a dusty rock or piece of wood that could easily blend into the road surface and be missed at your acknowledged speed of 25kph. If your front tire passed just to the right of said object, the object could impact that arm from the front causing the front brake to suddenly engage.

I.e. in your second picture:

[image]

Such an object would only have to be a few inches tall, one of the risks to such a small wheel with so much of the brake mechanics exposed like that. After flying through the air, being injured, dazed, etc., it would be easy to not notice the object, which may also have been tossed out of the way by the impact.

Comment: As I mentioned, I will post a picture of the crash site when I'm well enough to go there. I'd have noticed an object a few inches high, all the more so if my tyre ran over it. I do pay attention to the road.

Comment: I went to the scene of the accident, as you asked, but couldn't identify the exact spot, because the bump that caused the accident was so small.

Answer (score 2):

If both bikes can / have navigated bigger bumps without issue then I'd suspect that the 'half a centimeter' bump wasn't the cause of you being thrown off the bike, that it just happened to be there on the road where you fell off. If these both happened at the same point in the road I'd be more suspicious about it being the large scale road geometry rather than the small scale road geometry of the bump. Maybe the surface has a longish hump followed by a dip, such that it pushes the front of the bike up (several inches) and then a bike length later drops the front wheel into a dip while pushing the back wheel up... the effect would be to tip you forward as the handle bars dropped and the saddle kicked up under you. If you're way forward on the bike or you ride a short framed bike that might be enough to tip you off. I know from experience that some un-flat road surfaces have kicked me up on the saddle... and have dropped the bars out from under my hands... and I've learned to ride over that sort of terrain with my weight not fully on the saddle letting the bike buck around underneath me and using legs as suspension. With poor road maintenance where I live I'm regularly riding routes with bumps much bigger than half a centimeter on 23mm racing tyres running at 90+ psi.

As to why no-one else notices it? maybe they aren't travelling as fast. Maybe they ride in a different geometry. Try riding that part of the journey much slower, you should (1) not get thrown off and (2) have more time to feel the sequence of movements of the bike under you.

Photos of the road surface may help give a clue.

Comment: There was no hump followed by a dip, or anything usual prior to the single bump that threw me off. I've updated the question with photos.

Comment: I went to the scene of the accident, as you asked, but couldn't identify the exact spot, because the bump that caused the accident was so small

Answer (score 0):

You said that it’s when you hit a bump. Looking at your bike, that’s a big fender on the front. Hitting a bump with any amount of speed would cause the front tire to compress into the fender. Since it’s so large, that’s a lot of surface area to grab the wheel and lock it up to throw you. You had already mentioned the suspension was non-existent.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  How is the front tyre supposed to compress into the fender when the fender is obviously attached to the end of the fork where it will move together with the wheel?